# Reference request for a basic result on relative differents & discriminants

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am looking for a better reference for the results in this extremely short and elementary paper:

Tôyama, Hiraku,
`A note on the different of the composed field',
Kōdai Math. Sem. Rep. 7 (1955), 43–44.

You can find it here:
[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kodai-mathematical-journal/volume-7/issue-2/A-note-on-the-different-of-the-composed-field/10.2996/kmj/1138843605.full)

In case the link stops working, the primary theorem states that if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are finite extensions of a number field $K_0$ with compositum $K_3 = K_1K_2$, then $$\text{lcm}\left(\mathcal{D}_{K_1/K_0},\mathcal{D}_{K_2/K_0}\right) ~\big|~ \mathcal{D}_{K_3/K_0} ~\big|~ \mathcal{D}_{K_1/K_0}\mathcal{D}_{K_2/K_0}, $$
where $\mathcal{D}_{K_i/K_j}$ denotes the relative different.

As a corollary, if the relative discriminants $D_{K_1/K_0}$ and $D_{K_2/K_0}$ are relatively prime, then $$D_{K_3/K_0} =  D_{K_1/K_0}^{[K_2:K_0]} \cdot D_{K_2/K_0}^{[K_1:K_0]}.$$

It's a very elementary result, and I can find the statement of at least the corollary in several places, but only stated in the case where $K_0 = \mathbb{Q}$.  The Tôyama paper is a little frustrating to read because it contains some small errors, plus the typesetting is offensive to modern eyes.  I would expect this to be in a basic algebraic number theory book.  Does anyone know a nicer reference?

---

Edit: I meant to assume that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are linearly disjoint over $K_0$, so $K_1 \cap K_2 = K_0$.  (Algebraic closure fixed before-hand, etc.)  I think maybe Tôyama was assuming this tacitly.