# Discriminant of a compositum of number fields, a bound?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields, discriminant

Given two number fields $E$ and $F$, is there a bound on $|d_{EF}|$, the absolute value of the absolute discriminant of the compositum of fields $EF$, in terms of $d_E$, $d_F$, and the extension degrees ?

The actual problem I try to solve is slightly more specific: given a number field $F$, is there a bound on $|d_{F^n}|$ in terms of $d_F$ and the extension degrees, where $F^n$ is the normal closure of $F$ over $\mathbb Q$? We know that $F^n$ is the compositum of all the conjugates of $F$ over $\mathbb Q$, and in the particular case I study I know that there are at most $4$ of those conjugates. So a bound on the discriminant of any compositum of fields would help, but if there is a bound for the discriminant of the normal closure it would be even better.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719377/discriminant-of-a-compositum-of-number-fields-a-bound

Comment: Your questions are answered in a paper by Toyama cited in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137557/reference-request-for-a-basic-result-on-relative-differents-discriminants

Comment: Thank you! So if I'm not mistaken, we can deduce from his paper the following: with the same setting as in my original question, $d_{EF} \mid d_E^{[EF:E]}d_F^{[EF:F]}$.